JSX syntax error, Unexpected token, expected ","
I am trying to create a ios react JSX app but I keep getting this error and I dont know why. I coppied the ts file from my homescreen file that works so I'm confused on why I'm getting it in this file.
I think it maybe a jest.config.js error so I tried updating config file but that didnt help either.
I greatly appreciate any help you can give me.

PillScanner.ts: Unexpected token, expected "," (14:6)

  12 |   return (
  13 |     <ImageBackground
> 14 |       source={require('../assets/background.jpg')} 
     |       ^
  15 |       style={styles.background}
  16 |     >
  17 |       <View style={styles.bottomNav}>]

Here is my entire file:
import { View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

const PillScanner: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={require('../assets/background.jpg')} 
      style={styles.background}
    >
      <View style={styles.bottomNav}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Image
            source={require('../assets/home-icon.png')} // Example image for home icon
            style={styles.navIcon}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Image
            source={require('../assets/calendar-icon.png')} // Calendar icon image
            style={styles.navIcon}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Image
            source={require('../assets/user-icon.png')} // Example image for user icon
            style={styles.navIcon}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Image
            source={require('../assets/list-icon.png')} // Example image for list icon
            style={styles.navIcon}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  bottomNav: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 20,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)', 
    borderRadius: 15,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  navIcon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  },
});

export default PillScanner;


Ensure the file is saved as .tsx and not .ts since it includes JSX syntax

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This worked! Thank you! :)

The error you're seeing, "Unexpected token, expected ','", is likely due to a small syntax mistake in your PillScanner.ts file. This kind of error usually happens when there's a typo or a missing bracket or comma in the code. It’s a common issue that can be easily overlooked, but fixing these small errors should resolve the problem.
]

While this might be true in general, in this case it seems more likely that the issues comes from the file extension being .ts instead of .tsx. It seems like you have not tried to reproduce the issue as there is no syntax error with the provided code in a .tsx file.

Maybe the above error is occurred due to you unintentionally added ] symbol at the end of the
<View style={styles.bottomNav}>]

this View.
Please let me know if it is resolved. if not then also ping me.
